# How do you make the backtick symbol "`" on a scandinavian keyboard not a dead key? (WINDOWS LAPTOP)

Tags: javascript, keyboard

When I have to make this symbol ` I have to press space after pressing the backtick key and then backspace. Is there a way to remove the dead key feature. I feel template strings will be a hassle otherwise.

I have a windows laptop.

Please help!

I have tried searching for solutions but haven't been able to find any

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/414405/pressing-the-tilde-key-waits-for-a-second-key-stroke-how-do-i-disable-this

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=102134